# How to tune hyperparameters on 100 data sets generated by MICE

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter, mice

I am coding in Python and my data consists of 100 imputed data sets created by MICE in R.
I am running Scikit-learn ML (Supervised Regression) algorithms to improve the prediction of Warfarin. My aim is to find models with a lower MAE than Linear Regression. How can I combine these imputed data sets for the purpose of applying GridSearchCV?